# jQuery, how to clean localStorage and stop a function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
function myCustomFunction() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#autoplay').get(0).click();
    }, 2000);
}

var isAutoplay = localStorage.getItem('autoplay');

if (isAutoplay) {
    myCustomFunction();
}

$('#autoplay').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('autoplay', true);
    myCustomFunction();
});

// CLEAR THE LOCALSTORAGE
$('#stopplay').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('autoplay');
});
```

I assumed by clearing "localStorage" it would register "isAutoplay" to be false and in turn stop the myCustomFunction() function, but instead "localStorage.removeItem('autoplay');" doesn't seem to be clearing it.

How else can I stop the function from working by clicking on a link to stop the autoplay?

Thank you

Comment: What happens is logical : the autoplay callbacks call itself using the setTimeout. What's hard to get is what was your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what was your goal as your code does nothing useful. But maybe you want this :

```
var timer;
function myCustomFunction() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#autoplay').get(0).click();
    }, 2000);
}

var isAutoplay = localStorage.getItem('autoplay');

if (isAutoplay) {
    myCustomFunction();
}

$('#autoplay').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('autoplay', true);
    myCustomFunction();
});

// CLEAR THE LOCALSTORAGE and remove the timer
$('#stopplay').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('autoplay');
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer always simulates a `click()` on `$('#autoplay').get(0)` which calls `localStorage.setItem('autoplay', true);`.

You're in a loop.

To solve it you must separate the two operations, or cancel the timer manually when clicking `$('#stopplay')`.

More explanation would help me produce a proper code for you.